# How to add input value to URL in php

Tags: php, html

I have a question from php and I'm not expert in php.

1.I have html page with one form include a text box and submit button .

2.I have a static target url like this : https://example.com/invoice/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXXXXXXXX is just numbers and has 14 characters.

*** What I need is that my customer enter its 14 characters number in input text form and when it submit , goes to target url.I want to check input form for entry numbers too.

I make a sample form like this but not work:

```
        <form action="https://example.com/invoice" class="pey-form" method="get">
          <input type="text" id="peyid" name="peyid" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" maxlength="14" ><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

What can I do?

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP in this case, use javascript to listen to the form submission, and on submit append the input value to the form action URL.

Comment: Could submit to a php script to check/validate your input, then redirect to the desired page/url

Comment: how i can do it? i'm not so expert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hassan said , you can do this only with javascript.
This will redirect to the url what you desired.

```
document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = function(){
    this.setAttribute("action",this.getAttribute("action")+"/"+document.querySelector("[name=peyid]").value);
}
```

For example
If `document.querySelector("[name=peyid]").value = 12345678901234`  The url will look like `https://example.com/invoice/12345678901234?peyid=12345678901234`

So if you just need to redirect to that url you don't even need form just

```
<input type="text" id="peyid" name="peyid" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" maxlength="14" ><br><br>
<input type="button" value="submit">

<script>
    document.querySelector("[type=button]").onclick = function(){
        location.href = `https://example.com/invoice/${document.querySelector("[name=peyid]").value}`;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, the second part work  for me as well. just how I can set a condition for empty text box that give an error or not work?

Comment: You can simply use if else to make it. like `if(value != "") location.href = "url"; else alert("error");`

Comment: <script> document.querySelector("[type=button]").onclick = function(){ if("[value != "") location.href = https://example.com/invoice/${document.querySelector("[name=peyid]").value}; else alert("Please Fill The Box"); } </script>

I set this condition but not work

Comment: Did you declare `value` as `document.querySelector("[name=peyid]").value` ?
This should be work
`document.querySelector("[type=button]").onclick = function(){
        let value = document.querySelector("[name=peyid]").value;
        if(value != ""){
            location.href = `https://example.com/invoice/${value}`;
        }
        else{
            alert("Please Fill The Box");
        }
    } `

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP—to receive a `form` value, validate it, apply it to a URL, and redirect the client to that location, use [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post), [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), [string interpolation](https://riptutorial.com/php/example/22788/string-interpolation), and [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

/invoice/index.php:

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['peyid']) && preg_match("/^\d{14}$/", $_POST['peyid']) ) {

    header("Location: http://www.example.com/invoice/{$_POST['peyid']}");
    exit;

}

?>
<html><head><title>oops</title></head><body>An error occurred.</body></html>
```